# How to recover overwritten stashed changes?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I had some stashed changes. I totally forgot they are there so I added some files to the project (not committed nor stashed). Then I decided to switch branches and it prompted me with a message saying stash the uncommitted changes before switching to another branch, I did and then it prompted again saying that it will overwrite the older stashed changes. I hit OK and now here I am! I really need to know if there is a way to recover those overwritten stashed changes. I tried recovering from the log file in "../github/log" but I cant find them there.

Comment: I did not know stashes can be overwritten to begin with? What command(s) did you use?

Comment: Have you tried to run `git stash list` ?